# how redirect to a new window when a ads are clicked

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I got hooked up with the following scenario. I have a google ad with me that I wanted to display in my view file. I successfully achieved it but I require in this way like when user clicks on it he should redirected a new window where that content related to that ad should be open up. for reference I'm pasting my code related to my ad.Please help me out

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     google_ad_slot = "6257988877";
     google_ad_width = 200;
     google_ad_height = 200;
   </script>
   <script type="text/javascript"
   src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
   </script>
```

So when user clicks on it the advert should be opened in a new window. Any kind of help is welcome. Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, NO.

Your answer can be found at the google adsense support http://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/answer.py?answer=9737

Comment: Fix the link, it has an extra "a" in the end.

Comment: Sorry for the broken link ... and thanks to @Shadow Wizard for fixing it in time :)

Comment: Of course where redirected to me is true. But my client needs it. If you can help me out please help me.

Comment: @user838479 ? eh ?? Did you read the link ? It is not possible.

Comment: Yes, I read it and understood it but my client is not getting convinced. Is there any way.

Comment: @user838479, not without breaking the TOS of adsense and getting his account banned.

Answer (score 0):

The long answer: Maybe!
You could try to add an onLoad function that goes through all the anchor links of your page and adds for the Google ones a `target="_blank"` attribute.